# php within a function call a constructor and initialize object

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm not familiar with php OOP and now I'm in some trouble. I'm developing my project in structured programming (not OOP) and I have included a class (made by someone else) and within my structured function I must initialize the class and do things. If you don't understand what I have typed here, please watch the code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/SourceQuery/SourceQuery.class.php';

function get_server_info($ip, $port){

    define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', $ip );
    define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', $port );
    define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     5 );
    define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery :: GOLDSOURCE );

    $Query = new SourceQuery( );

    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

        $result = (array)$Query->GetInfo();

    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        $result = array('Players' => 0, 'MaxPlayers' => 0);
    }

    $Query->Disconnect( );
    unset($Query);
    return array('players' => $result['Players'], 'max_players' => $result['MaxPlayers']);
}
?>
```

Basically I have created a function called get_server_info which constructs a SourceQuery object. I'm querying Counter-Strike servers for number of players and max players.

I don't know if this is correct programatically (mixing structured with OOP). I don't want to change code or create methods in the class, I want to use my function. I'm getting result for each call (get_server_info()), but the problem is every result is same !

For example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++){
   $result = get_server_info('66.55.44.3'.$i, 27015);
   echo $result['players'].' - '.$result['max_players'].'<br />';
}
```

The result is the same for any server ! (Yes, they are all up and running). When I'm checking the servers on my server viewer program they have different number of players, but my result from this loop is the same ! I don't know why.

If I query manually one by one I'm getting the correct result.

I think it's because the object isn't deleted or .... I don't know.

Comment: Where do you exactly have this `which constructs a SourceQuery object` in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're trying to overwrite a constant. (`define`)

Define the constants somewhere in your code outside any function and pass `$id` and `$port` 
directly to the class. And where do you have `$Query` initialized?

Try:

```
define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     5 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery :: GOLDSOURCE );

function get_server_info($ip, $port){

    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( $ip, $port, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );
```

Comment: Now it's working! The problem it was caused because I have used constants.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot

```
$Query = new SourceQuery( );
```

See [here](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query-Class/blob/master/Example.php) an example.